# running groovy script and classes through maven

Tags: maven, groovy

I searched for possible cause and solution, but still don't understand what am I doing wrong
i try to run groovy script from maven my pom.xml is:

```
    `<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                                                      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.sonatype.mcookbook</groupId>
<artifactId>groovy-script-ex</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>groovy-script-ex</name>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-bsf</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <!-- any version of Groovy \>= 1.5.0 should work here -->
        <version>2.4.12</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*test*.*</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        <goal>execute</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${pom.basedir}/src/Cagri_groovy/testfirst.groovy</source>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

'

when i run build job i get

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute (default) on project groovy-script-ex: startup failed, script1511249885612.groovy: 1: expecting EOF, found 'TESTLERİ' @ line 1, column 41.
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

my groovy script is testfirst.groovy

`

```
package Cagri_groovy;
    import Cagri_groovy.Application
    import Cagri_groovy.firstgclass


    def object=new firstgclass()
    object.openBrowser()
    object.setUserName("abc")
    object.setPassword("123456")
    object.Login(object.UserName,object.Password)
    object.Sayfa_Acma("test.jsf")
    Application.open_connection()
    object.Simulator()
    Application.close_connection()`
```

my build job name is groovy TESTLERİ hen i changed it to test i receive
my build job name is groovy testleri i changed build job name to test now i receive

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute (default) on project groovy-script-ex: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5:execute: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ModuleNode.getStarImports()Ljava/util/List;
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.gmaven:gmaven-plugin:1.5
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/gmaven-plugin/1.5/gmaven-plugin-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-api/1.5/gmaven-runtime-api-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/feature/gmaven-feature-api/1.5/gmaven-feature-api-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-loader/1.5/gmaven-runtime-loader-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/feature/gmaven-feature-support/1.5/gmaven-feature-support-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/gmaven/runtime/gmaven-runtime-support/1.5/gmaven-runtime-support-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/gshell/gshell-io/2.4/gshell-io-2.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/qdox/qdox/1.12/qdox-1.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/file-management/1.2.1/file-management-1.2.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[10] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-shared-io/1.1/maven-shared-io-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[11] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/xbean/xbean-reflect/3.4/xbean-reflect-3.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[12] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/log4j/log4j/1.2.12/log4j-1.2.12.jar
[ERROR] urls[13] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging-api/1.1/commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[14] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/com/google/collections/google-collections/1.0/google-collections-1.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[15] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-impl/2.0.4.1/maven-reporting-impl-2.0.4.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[16] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.1/plexus-interpolation-1.1.jar
[ERROR] urls[17] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/commons-validator/commons-validator/1.2.0/commons-validator-1.2.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[18] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.7.0/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[19] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/commons-digester/commons-digester/1.6/commons-digester-1.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[20] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.0.4/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[21] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/oro/oro/2.0.8/oro-2.0.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[22] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
[ERROR] urls[23] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-core/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-core-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[24] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[25] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.4/maven-reporting-api-2.0.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[26] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-site-renderer/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-site-renderer-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[27] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-i18n/1.0-beta-7/plexus-i18n-1.0-beta-7.jar
[ERROR] urls[28] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-velocity/1.1.7/plexus-velocity-1.1.7.jar
[ERROR] urls[29] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/velocity/velocity/1.5/velocity-1.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[30] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-decoration-model/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-decoration-model-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[31] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2/commons-collections-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[32] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-apt/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-apt-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[33] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-fml/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-fml-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[34] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xdoc/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-xdoc-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[35] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-module-xhtml/1.0-alpha-10/doxia-module-xhtml-1.0-alpha-10.jar
[ERROR] urls[36] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[37] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.5.10/slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar
[ERROR] urls[38] = file:/var/jenkins_home/.m2/repository/org/sonatype/gossip/gossip/1.2/gossip-1.2.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/jenkins_home/workspace/test/pom.xml to org.sonatype.mcookbook/groovy-script-ex/1.0-SNAPSHOT/groovy-script-ex-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

my groovy file and pom files are in svn. 
i try to change path in xml file but not working. it always gives error is there way to correct this problem?
thanks for your help

Comment: my build job name is groovy testleri i changed build job name to test now i receive

Answer (score 0):

when i changed pom to this
it worked also i changed my build name to test

```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0                        
                             http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.sonatype.mcookbook</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-script-ex</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>groovy-script-ex</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-bsf</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
      <!-- any version of Groovy \>= 1.5.0 should work here -->
      <version>2.4.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>

       <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.12.3</version>
   <!-- <configuration> -->
     <!-- <failIfNoTests>false</failIfNoTests> -->
     <!-- <includes> -->
       <!-- <include>**/*test*.*</include> -->
     <!-- </includes> -->
   <!-- </configuration> -->
 </plugin>
    <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
   <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
    <configuration>
                <providerSelection>1.8</providerSelection>
            </configuration> 
   <executions>
     <execution>
     <phase>generate-resources</phase>
       <goals>
        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
         <goal>compile</goal>
         <goal>generateTestStubs</goal>
         <goal>testCompile</goal>
          <goal>execute</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
              <source>${pom.basedir}/src/Cagri_groovy/testfirst.groovy</source>
            </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  </project>
```

Comment: While it's great, that you document your answer here, it would be even greater, if you could add what is actually changed.